# e.preventDefault doesn't stop form from submitting

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the below code which fails to work as expected. Whenever the status returned is 1, the code does not end in the first if statement but continues to execute returning to the top and executing the ajax request:

```
$("form#myForm").submit(function(e){
        var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/app/user",
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            async: false,
            success: function (data) {
                var parseData = JSON.parse(data);
                var message = parseData.msg;
                var status = parseData.status;

                if (status == "1"){
                    console.log("one");
                } else if(status == "2"){
                    console.log("two");
                } else if (status == 3){
                    console.log("three");
                }
            },
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: e.preventDefault(); before the var = formatData = new ......
also make sure that your $("form#myForm")  selection is correct

Comment: @GlupiJas if `$("form#myForm")` was incorrect, the function would never be called at all, you nailed it on the `e.preventDefault()` though

Comment: synchronous requests are a bad idea, you should not be using it.

Answer (score 1):

Your e.preventDefault() should be called before the ajax.