# e.PreventDefault and ajx submit not working together [return true] is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function to check whether email exist, but I want to submit the form only if the email doesn't exist

So I wrote following function:

```
$("#form-1").on("submit",function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
    var given_email=document.getElementById("email");

     var data = $("#form-1").serialize();
     $.ajax({    
            type : 'POST',
            url  : 'check.php',
            data : data,
            beforeSend: function() { 
                $(".submit").val('sending ...');
            },
            success :  function(response) {

                var response = JSON.parse(response);      
                if(response.status=='error'){
                  alert("Sorry This Email Already Used ");
                         return false;               
                } if(response.status=='true') {
                    return true;
                    $(this).submit();
                }
            }
        });
});
```

Now if it return true also i cant submit the form . Please help.
 i saw this question and answer [e.preventDefault doesn't stop form from submitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488654/e-preventdefault-doesnt-stop-form-from-submitting) . But no effect

> Notes

even i tried

```
  if(response.status=='true') { $("#form-1").submit(); } .
```

But this also not working

Comment: I think you'll need to make another  call for this

Comment: `this` inside your callback is not your form element. Also your return is before calling submit so it is never called. And your return statements in the callback are not part of the outer scope flow, meaning you arent doing a return in the submit events callback

Comment: First of all ajax is a  asynchronous call so before getting response your form will submit, instead of you should make that ajax call on blur event of text box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return statement is returning before the form is submitted

```
if(response.status == 'true') {
  //return true; // returns before the form is submitted
  $(this).submit();
  return true; // move return after submit
}
```

**Suggestion**

You are thinking about this, the wrong way, let `PHP` handle the checking and insert in the backend.

**First Solution**

In your PHP do something like

```
$querycheck = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Persons");
$countrows = mysqli_num_rows($querycheck );;
if($countrows == '1')
{
  echo json_encode(['message' => 'Sorry This Email Already Used']);
}
else
{
 // insert statement here 
 echo json_encode(['message' => 'Submitted']);
}
```

In your JS

```
$("#form-1").on("submit",function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
var given_email=document.getElementById("email");

 var data = $("#form-1").serialize();
 $.ajax({    
        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'check.php',
        data : data,
        beforeSend: function() { 
            $(".submit").val('sending ...');
        },
        success :  function(response) {

            var response = JSON.parse(response);
            alert(response.message); // display the message here to the user.    
        }
    });
 });
```

**Second Solution**

save the form in a variable.

```
$("#form-1").on("submit",function(e){
 e.preventDefault();

const form = $(this); // get the current form

var given_email=document.getElementById("email");

 var data = $("#form-1").serialize();
 $.ajax({    
        type : 'POST',
        url  : 'check.php',
        data : data,
        beforeSend: function() { 
            $(".submit").val('sending ...');
        },
        success :  function(response) {

            var response = JSON.parse(response);      
            if(response.status=='error'){
              alert("Sorry This Email Already Used ");
                     return false;               
            } if(response.status=='true') {
                form.submit(); // submit the form here
                return true;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: it is not about the message . it is about form submit . i cant submit the form again

Comment: Why do you want to submit the form again? my suggestion here is to let the backed deal with the checking of email, if it exists it reruns the message, if doesn't it insert the mail, simple. Instead of trying to send the form twice.

Comment: You'll end up making two requests, instead of making one requests and PHP will do the heavy lifting in the back-end and return appropriate message.

Comment: @abilasher I've added a second solution.